# Run macro when a template is opened

Tags: vba, templates, outlook, automation, oft

I have a macro in an outlook template (oft). It changes certain text in the subject and the body of the mail. I would like to know if it is possible to make this macro execute automatically when I open the template.

Thank you in advance,
Santi

Comment: There is an `Application_Startup()` event, look it up.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your template does not contain any code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865637%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
Sub CreateFromTemplate() 
 Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\statusrep.oft") 

 ' put the code you think is in the template here

 MyItem.Display
End Sub
```